# Does Chocolina have something for me after I complete her mini-quest in Sazh: Heads or Tails?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In the *Sazh: Heads or Tails?* DLC, you need to get 30 medals in order to complete the main quest. I got those medals via the poker mini-game before realizing you can get three from completing a mini-quest for Chocolina.

I completed the mini-quest, and now the game says that Chocolina doesn't have anything for me now, but that I should continue playing card games and check back later.

Does she actually have something, or is this just a cue for people who still need more medals? If she does have something, did I miss out by not completing the quest at the appropriate time (before completing the main quest)?

If not, how many card games should I play before checking back?

Comment: AFAIK, you didn't miss out on anything.  Did you find out in the end if she did have something for you?

Comment: @GlenWheeler I've been wrapped up in work and haven't been able to play. Keep meaning to revisit this question as it's earned me a Tumbleweed badge :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this message when talking to Chocolina, there's more to her story and she does have more for you.

To test this, I closed the gate and restarted the DLC. Before winning any medals at the card tables, I went to see Chocolina and completed the three chocobo chick fetch quest she had: haughty, hermit, and manic. As before, once complete, she just smiled and I got the dialog saying she didn't have anything for me right now.

I then went and played an entire game of Texas Hold'em, got a few dozen medals, and visited her again. This time, she had two new chocobo chick fetch quests: lovebird and conniving.

Once you collect this second round of chocobo chicks, she'll ask you a trivia question about all the chicks. If answered correctly, there'll be a cut scene where Chocolina explains more about herself. Afterwards, talking to her will give you the option of having the chocobo chicks follow you around while in Serendipity.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe I have been stuck in your boat as well, but after a couple minutes of searching I found a review that (possibly) explains everything.

http://www.themogblog.com/2012/02/28/the-dlc-downlow-final-fantasy-xiii-2-sazh-heads-or-tails/

According to this particular link (and xbox360achievements.org forums) all you can possibly get is that little twist of the story that the DLC has to offer. I myself am quite pleased with how it ended, though I am somewhat disappointed that you couldn't get anything else from Chocolina after finishing her mini-quest (which nets you those few coins). Hope this sums things up for you bud! I know it did for me :P

Comment: And of course there's that little twist with Chocolina, but I'm sure no one cares about that too much.